# Suricata IDS not working with NordVPN connected

Tags: vpn, suricata

I configured suricata.yaml file to detect intrusion in any interface and it works well *without* NordVPN.

When I test Suricata by visiting:

```
curl http://testmynids.org/uid/index.html
```

Result of `sudo tail /var/log/suricata/fast.log | grep 2100498`:

```
08/14/2023-22:28:35.580451  [**] [1:2100498:7] GPL ATTACK_RESPONSE id check returned root [**] [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 64.12.213.57:80 -> 192.168.15.17:3354
```

However, when I connect to NordVPN (`nordvpn connect us-ca55`) the test traffic is not being detected.

Any ideas on how to properly set up the yaml config file? My intuition tells me it is just one or two lines of code, but I can't find where.

I used `ip a` to find the interfaces, tried 3 of them, also `any` but is not detecting the test traffic with the VPN connected.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I think you are missing some details here. For instance, "when I connect NordVPN" -- how are you doing that? Why do you think that this is a suricata issue and not a basic networking issue?

Comment: I'm connecting NordVPN via CLI. In fact I don't know if it is really a suricata config issue. The point is when I connect the VPN, suricata does not log the test traffic. I don't know how the VPN tunnel works in the interface.

Comment: ... and what command do you use? Do you get a new interface when you run it?

Comment: `nordvpn connect us-ca55` in the CLI, no interface is created, it just tell me `You are connected to Canada - United States #66 (ca-us66.nordvpn.com)!`.

Comment: Probably because you are telling Suricata to listen to a physical interface, and NordVPN creates a virtual interface.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was at ports used by NordVPN and interface.

These lines of code in `suricata.yaml` solved the problem:

```
port-groups:

FILE_DATA_PORTS: "[$HTTP_PORTS,110,143,443,51820]"
TCP_PORTS: "[1723,1701]"
UDP_PORTS: "[500,4500,1194]"

interface: nordlynx
```